# Is there a way to preserve the Content Type Hub 's column setting (such as drop down choices) when using the CT inside a new site collection

Tags: 2013, development, content-type, content-type-hub

This is my first time where i use Content Type hub. but i found this scenario which i can not understand:-

1. i create a new Site collection (CSA) which act as a Content type hub.
2. inside this CSA i add 5 choices for a column named Priority.
3. i add this site column to a new CT and i publish the CT.
4. now i create a new site collection (CSB), which already have the Priority column , but with 3 choices (built-in choices).
5. now from SCB i create a new list and i chnage its CT to use the shared CT .
6. the result is that i will get only 3 choices inside the Priority column and not 5 as defined inside the content type hub site.

so does this mean when using a content type hub , the content type's columns will be overridden inside each site ?  and in my case if i want the Priority column to contain 5 choices inside SCB, then i can not manage this from the CT hub site collection ??
Thanks